# What's the intended way to pass a list?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe6

I have an existing class, that has an existing method, that allows you to pass it a list of *stuff*:

```
TContoso = class(TSkyrim)
public
   procedure AddObjects(Objects: TList);
end;
```

And so, in the before-times, someone could pass a `TList` or a `TObjectList` to the method:

```
var
   list: TList;

list := TObjectList.Create(True);
contoso.AddObjects(list);
```

It didn't matter, as `TObjectList` was a `TList`. My method was flexible; it could take either.

### Now in the after times

Now in the after times, i prefer typed lists:

```
var
   list: TList<TGrobber>;

list := TObjectList<TGrobber>.Create(True);
contoso.AddObjects(list);
```

Of course that doesn't compile, as neither `TList<T>` nor `TObjectList<T>` descend from `TList`. Which isn't such a problem. I intuitiavely understand that i don't actually need a `TList`, i just need something that is *"enumerable"*:

Based on my experience in the .NET FCL, that means i simply need to declare the parameter is `IEnumerable`, because **everything** is enumerable:

- `IEnumerable<T>` comes from `IEnumerable`
- `ICollection` comes from `IEnumerable`
- `ICollection<T>` comes from `IEnumerable`
- `IList` comes from `IEnumerable`
- `IList<T>` comes from `IEnumerable`
- `List` comes from `IEnumerable`
- `List<T>` comes from `IEnumerable`

So i would do something like:

```
TContoso = class(TSkyrim)
public
   procedure AddObjects(Objects: IEnumerable);
end;
```

Except the Delphi BCL doesn't allow the polymorphism that .NET world allows; the things that are enumerable don't implement the `IEnumerable` interface:

```
TList = class(TObject)
public
   function GetEnumerator: TListEnumerator;
end;

TObjectList = class(TList);

TList<T> = class(TEnumerable<T>)
public
   function GetEnumerator: TEnumerator<T>;
end;

TObjectList<T> = class(TList<T>);
```

Without the typing, how does the compiler know a type is enumerable?

[Delphi uses secret hard-coded magic.](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE7/en/Declarations_and_Statements):

> the class or interface must implement a prescribed collection pattern. A type that implements the collection pattern must have the following attributes:
>   - The class or interface must contain a public instance method called `GetEnumerator()`. The `GetEnumerator()` method must return a class, interface, or record type.
>   The class, interface, or record returned by `GetEnumerator()` must contain a public instance method called `MoveNext()`. The `MoveNext()` method must return a **Boolean**.
>   - The class, interface, or record returned by `GetEnumerator()` must contain a public instance, read-only property called `Current`. The type of the `Current` property must be the type contained in the collection.

What is the way that the language designers intended me to use enumerables in my code?

- What do i declare the type of paramater
- how do i check for the presence of a method called `GetEnumerator`?
- how do i call the method `GetEnumerator`?
- how do i call the `Current` property?
- how do i call the `Next` method?

For example:

```
TContoso = class(TSkyrim)
public
   procedure AddObjects(const Objects);
end;    

procedure TContoso.AddObjects(const Objects);
var
   o: TObject;
   enumerator: TObject;
   bRes: Boolean;
begin
   //for o in Objects do
   //   InternalAdd(nil, '', o);

   if not HasMethod(Objects, 'GetEnumerator') then
      Exit;

    enumerator := InvokeMethod(Objects, 'GetEnumerator');

    if not HasMethod(enumerator, 'MoveNext') then
       Exit;

    bRes := InvokeMethod(enumerator, 'MoveNext');

    while bRes do
    begin
       if HasMethod(enumerator, 'Current');
           InternallAdd(nil, '', InvokeMethod(enumerator, 'Current'));

       bRes := InvokeMethod(enumerator, 'MoveNext');
    end;
end;
```

What is the intended way to pass *"an enumerable bag of stuff"*?

## Hack

```
TContoso = class(TSkyrim)
public
   procedure AddObjects(Objects: TList); overload;
   procedure AddObjects(Objects: TList<T>); overload;
end;
```

There must be a reason the designers chose not to have `IList` implement `IEnumerable`. There must be a compile time mechanism to iterate a list. But what is that reason, and what is that way.

Comment: I don't think you can do this as is, at least using the standard RTL.  The generic containers return typed enumerators - that is a TEnumerator<T>.  The compiler understands how to use this but does a type check that your foreach variable is type compatible with T.  However, someone may have produced a suitable set of generic container classes which have non-generic ancestor types containing the non-type dependent code since this is the technique for controlling ultimate compile size.  It may be worth checking Spring4D latest release.

Comment: You could add an `AsEnumerable` method to the containers. But a better library (Spring) would come with what you need out of the box I suspect.

Comment: I believe it's a pretty good request to QC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TObjectList<T>` derives from `TList<T>`, so use that as your parameter, making the method itself a Generic if you need to support multiple object types in the list, and then use a **for-in loop** to enumerate the list (which also works for the non-Generic `TList` and various other container classes):

[Iteration Over Containers Using For statements](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE8/en/Declarations_and_Statements#Iteration_Over_Containers_Using_For_statements)

```
Type
  TContoso = class(TSkyrim)
  public
    procedure AddObjects(Objects: TList); overload;
    procedure AddObjects<T: class>(Objects: TList<T>); overload;
  end;

procedure TContoso.AddObjects(Objects: TList);
var
  Obj: Pointer;
begin
  for Obj in Objects do
  begin
    // use TObject(Obj) as needed...
  end;
end;

procedure TContoso.AddObjects<T>(Objects: TList<T>);
var
  Obj: T;
begin
  for Obj in Objects do
  begin
    // use Obj as needed...
  end;
end;
```

```
var
   list: TList;

list := TObjectList.Create(True);
contoso.AddObjects(list);
```

```
var
  list: TList<TGrobber>;

list := TObjectList<TGrobber>.Create(True);
contoso.AddObjects<TGrobber>(list);
```

Let the compiler validate the presence of `GetEnumerator()` and the sub-methods of the returned enumerator class.  Don't try to handle it manually (if you want to do that, you have to use RTTI for it).  Besides, `for-in` loops have built-in support for other types of containers (arrays, strings, sets, and records) that do not expose `GetEnumerator()` but are otherwise enumerable.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously the classic VMT (Virtual Method Table) structure didn't support multiple inheritance, so they didn't want anything enumerable to have to descent from say a TEnumerable that was descending from TObject since that would be too restrictive.

So they used that hack with the specific method signature that had to be in your class, forcing you to use the HasMethod/InvokeMethod. So indeed your methods that get passed anything "enumerable" would then be of the form "procedure TContoso.AddObjects(const Objects)"

Comment: Huh? Delphi has supported implementing multiple interfaces in a single class for a very long time. You don't need full multiple inheritance for that. And the existing `IEnumerable` is an interface, not some class `TEnumerable` like you suggest.

Comment: I'm not speaking of full multiple inheritance C++ style. I think when I first started using Delphi they didn't have interfaces support

Comment: I know IEnumerable is an interface, but when you don't have interfaces support, you'd be forced to use a class, or use Reflection-style (or Introspection if you prefer) tricks if your runtime supports such and you want to be more flexible. BTW, have you seen this one (back from 2006)? http://blogs.encodo.ch/news/view_article.php?id=11

Comment: http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/30125 - "The first version of Delphi to support interfaces was Delphi 3. But there was a way to use and develop COM interfaces even in Delphi 2. How was that possible? The answer is simple. If you ignore the fact that a class can implement more than one interface, you can think of an interface as a pure abstract class."

Comment: *" they didn't want anything enumerable to have to descent from say a TEnumerable"*. They could have made those things implement `IEnumerable`. No reason to descend from a `TEnumerable`.

Comment: interfaces didn't exist in Delphi from the start. So they designed without them and then they had to keep backwards compatibility obviously